# iPhone custom navigation bar with custom UIBarButtonItems

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create a custom navigation bar with title and two custom baritems.
What I've done so far:
 1. subclass a UINavigationBar
 2. override `-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect`  method, to draw image as a background

Now I get stuck when making right bar button item.
In my CustomBar class I've overriden `pushNavigationItem` method as follows:

```
- (void)pushNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated {
     [super pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
     item.rightBarButtonItem.customView.frame = CGRectMake(250, 5, 60,30); 
}
```

and in my view controller I've done something like:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO]
```

but I always get SIGABRT when calling

```
[super pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```

If I leave that line out, everything runs fine, but there is no button in the navigation bar.

What is the proper way to add custom bar button item to custom navigation bar?

EDIT:
For clarification, I've added an image.

This is what I need.
[image]

I'm trying to create the logout button on the right

Comment: You don't actually show how you're instantiating your `CustomBar` class. Are you subclassing `UINavigationController`?

Comment: I am subclassing UINavigationBar. I make UINavigationController in a nib, set its navigation bar to my CustomNavBar class and load the controller from a nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing`navigationController` while setting the item ? I used to do that for setting the title, never used to get the title.

Try `[[self  navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:yourButton];`

In your case :

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;`
```

Comment: Thanx, I've changed to [self navigationItem] , but I'm still getting the SIGABRT when calling the super method. Do you know why does that happen?

Comment: What is `item` in your `[super pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO]` method ? I'm guessing you'd get a SIGABRT if it isn't of the type `UINavigationItem`

Comment: it is a UINavigationItem passed to the method

Comment: Sorry then i have no idea, but i'd definitely double check the `item` that is being passed, check if it is `alloc`ed properly or not.